# Why is my taxonomy term name no longer outputting?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have created a custom node with a field where you can select one tag from a list of a custom taxonomy term (location)

I was originally using this to print out the name of the selected tag for the node:

```
echo $field_location[0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
```

However it has since stopped working (it now outputs NULL). All I have done since is remove an unrelated field in the content type.

Now when i do a var dump of `$field_location` all I get is:

> array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["tid"]=> string(1) "1" } } }

Wheras before I had a load of extra stuff like the name of the tag etc...

Anyone have any ideas what's happened?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Structure > Content types > Article > Manage display, for Article for example. If your field is in Hidden section (bottom of the page) then change Format of this field to other than Hidden.

Comment: Nope, its not that, checked all that and everything's fine. Nothing hidden.

Comment: do dpm($content['field_location']); for debug or print render($content['field_location']); to print in node, and question -where you do this - on node template or in preprocess func?